# TextField (with recycler, viewpager or something else )

Tags: android-recyclerview, android-viewpager

What is the correct way of implementing this kind of view

[image]

Age Categories are dynamic. And it may be more than 3.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement it through `Recycler view`, even I did in one of my project. I had created number line, and added numbers dynamically. Also I have used `ViewPager2`.

[image]